# Convert spreadsheet into a pdf with apps script - getting html result

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, blob, export-to-pdf

I need to make a function to convert my spreadsheet into pdf file.
I followed the steps described in this website : https://xfanatical.com/blog/print-google-sheet-as-pdf-using-apps-script/

When i run the script, i have an html result instead of a .pdf as i wish.

[Html result instead of .pdf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtLsy.png)

I spent some hours to understand how its work but can't find a solution for this.

Here is the part of code I used :

```
function exportAsPDF() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  var blob = _getAsBlob(spreadsheet.getUrl() + '#gid=' + sheetId) 
  _exportBlob(blob, spreadsheet.getName(), spreadsheet)
}
function _getAsBlob(url, sheet, range) {
  var rangeParam = ''
  var sheetParam = ''
  if (range) {
    rangeParam =
      '&r1=' + (range.getRow() - 1)
      + '&r2=' + range.getLastRow()
      + '&c1=' + (range.getColumn() - 1)
      + '&c2=' + range.getLastColumn()
  }
  spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId(),
  pivotSourceDataSheetId=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getSheetId()
  if (sheet) {
    sheetParam = '&gid=' + sheet.getSheetId()
  }
  // A credit to https://gist.github.com/Spencer-Easton/78f9867a691e549c9c70
  // these parameters are reverse-engineered (not officially documented by Google)
  // they may break overtime.
  var exportUrl = url.replace(/\/edit.*$/, '')
      + '/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'
      + '&size=LETTER'
      + '&portrait=true'
      + '&fitw=true'       
      + '&top_margin=0.75'              
      + '&bottom_margin=0.75'          
      + '&left_margin=0.7'             
      + '&right_margin=0.7'           
      + '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'
      + '&pagenum=UNDEFINED' // change it to CENTER to print page numbers
      + '&gridlines=true'
      + '&fzr=FALSE'
      + sheetParam
      + rangeParam
  console.log('URL = ' + exportUrl)
  Logger.log('exportUrl=' + exportUrl)
  var response
  var i = 0
  for (; i < 5; i += 1) {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(exportUrl, {
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
      headers: { 
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      },
    })
    console.log('response = ' + response)
    if (response.getResponseCode() === 429) {
      // printing too fast, retrying
      Utilities.sleep(3000)
    } else {
      console.log('test')
      break
    }
  }
  
  if (i === 5) {
    throw new Error('Printing failed. Too many sheets to print.')
  }
  
  return response.getBlob()
}
```

I tried to change my url variable with adding the GID after the KEY but got the same result.
I tried to change the url variable with keep off the Replace() function and changing the format but got the same result aswell.

Also, I tried to add some logs in my execution to explore some variables, I don't know what it means but I found that my html result is in fact my "response" variable :
[My "response" variable in log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrRxi.png)

I hope someone met this problem already and succeed to solve it to help me ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Hmmm I just tried this out myself and I was able to get a PDF of my spreadsheet, I didn't change anything (I grabbed the missing functions from the first link you shared), so not sure why it's not working for you.